# Revert deleted Spock test cases from .class file

Tags: java, spock, testcase

Accidently I have deleted spock test case .groovy file and now I have only respective .class file.

Please let me know how to convert it from .class to spock test case

Answer (score 0):

Try [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca)
open the class and see if the groovy code still there (probably converted?)